# Refactoring repetitive guard statements

Tags: c, refactoring

I've defined a method that calculates the odds of winning and returns the amount payed to the player. I originally had written this the most obvious way of accomplishing this task, but I really would like to know the best way of refactoring this to minimize the amount of work the computer is performing. Here's my function:

```
int getPay(int winningOdds, int payOut)
{
    winningOdds = rand() % MAXIMUM_ODDS + MINIMUM_ODDS;

    if(winningOdds == 1)
    {
        payOut = 4000;
        printf("Jackpot!  - %d\n", payOut);
    }
    else if(winningOdds <= 2)
    {
        payOut = 1000;
        printf("Coins won - %d\n", payOut);
    }
    else if(winningOdds <= 3)
    {
        payOut = 500;
        printf("Coins won - %d\n", payOut);
    }
    else if(winningOdds <= 40)
    {
        payOut = 100;
        printf("Coins won - %d\n", payOut);
    }
    else if(winningOdds <= 50)
    {
        payOut = 50;
        printf("Coins won - %d\n", payOut);
    }
    else if(winningOdds <= 75)
    {
        payOut = 25;
        printf("Coins won - %d\n", payOut);
    }
    else if(winningOdds <= 1000)
    {
        payOut = 10;
        printf("Coins won - %d\n", payOut);
    }
    else if(winningOdds <= 3000)
    {
        payOut = 5;
        printf("Coins won - %d\n", payOut);
    }
    else if(winningOdds <= 5000)
    {
        payOut = 3;
        printf("Coins won - %d\n", payOut);
    }
    else if(winningOdds <= 10000)
    {
        payOut = 1;
        printf("Coins won - %d\n", payOut);
    }

    return payOut;
 }
```

Comment: For one thing, you can move the printf outside.

Comment: Being that they're indeed displaying the same information that would make sense. Since I have one display message for the jackpot, I could make a method specifically for that one message. Anything else @KarthikT

Comment: Dude, Load your program into a debugger and you'll see how little work it's doing... Seriously, you probably won't even see any of this code on a debugger because its so quick.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this style, you need to fill in the array of `Payout`

```
struct Payout{
    int winningOdds, payOut;
};

int getPay(int winningOdds, int payOut)
{
    Payout payout[] = {{1,4000},{2,1000}....};
    int numElem = sizeof(payout)/sizeof(payout[0]);

    winningOdds = rand() % MAXIMUM_ODDS + MINIMUM_ODDS;
    for(int i=0;i<numElem ;i++){
        if(winningOdds <=payout[i].winningOdds){
            payOut = payout[i].payout;
            break;
        }
    }
    printf("Coins won - %d\n", payOut);

}
```

Comment: I never thought of this, would you mind explaining what you did here?

Comment: Your `if` conditions are all of the form `if(a<=x) b=y;` So I make a list of `(x,y)` and go through them in a loop. The list is the payout array.

Comment: Awesome solution, I was going through design patterns trying to find out a more precise way of defining my slot machine. At glance, I noticed did you didn't declare x. Did you mean to say payout[numElem]?