# What is an alternative to oversized switch?

Tags: java, android, performance

I'm in the process of integrating a pseudo-search capability in my app. I have a search widget that gives out a list of search hints (these hints come from a fts3 sqlite table). When a user clicks on a search hint, a corresponding sqlite table will populate a listView.

I need a way to identify what table will populate the list based on the selected search hint. I'm thinking of doing something like this:

```
switch(search_hint){
    case(search_hint_1):  useTable(table_1);
                          break;
    case(search_hint_2):  useTable(table_2);
                          break;
    case(search_hint_3):  useTable(table_1 + table_2); // Case when I need to use
                          break;                       // two tables for ListView
}
```

I'm sure this is a possible solution but what if there are several (hundreds or thousands) of cases? Can anyone suggest a better way to face this?

Answer (score 3):

If you can, make the mapping into an array of pairs of some sort, then you can just go through them all with a `for-loop` and an `if`. Similar to my suggestion in [Refactoring repetitive guard statements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14681923/refactoring-repetitive-guard-statements/14682024#14682024). 
You would need to create a pair like class that holds the hint and the table.

Either that, or create an actual map. and use search_hint as the key.

```
Map< /*insert hint type here*/,Table> mapTable;
```

For example.

Answer (score 2):

I think the feasible way as per my thought.. Using **HashMap Key-Value** pair.. (Only Pseudo code)

```
Map<Integer,String> mapTable = new HashMap<Integer,String>();
mapTable.put(search_hint_1,table_1);
.
.
.
```

And just access `useTable(mapTable.get(search_hint));`

Answer (score 1):

`switch` statement is an anti-pattern in object oriented design (see [Object Thinking](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0735619654)). You should use inheritance instead.

Answer (score 0):

Put the information in the search hint table.
You need to think a bit on the different cases you have and how they can be broken up into small configurable pieces.

```
search_hint_1  table_1
search_hint_2          table_2
search_hint_3  table_1 table_2
```

Answer (score 0):

Use Enumerator. Like :

```
private static enum DojoDecider {   

    search_hint_1(table_1),
    search_hint_2(table_2);     

    private Table var;      

    private DojoDecider(Table var) {
        this.var = var;
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("unused")
    public Table getVar() {
        return var;
    }           
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
final int[] hintArray = {search_hint_1, search_hint_2, search_hint_3};
final String[] tableArray = {table_1, table_2, table_3};

private Map<Integer,String> hintMap = new HashMap<Integer,String>();

// Populate the map, probably at onCreate() of your activity
for(int i=0; i<hintArray.length; i++) {
    hintMap.put(hintArray[i], tableArray[i]);
}

// When you want to get it
useTable(hintMap.get(search_hint));
```